# How to get rightmost characters plus text between double quotes using regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a python list containing something like this:

```
['"Some-text" {12345-ab123-cd456}', '"Some-Another-text2" {54321-ab123-cd456}]'
```

The result I wish to get is:

```
text, 12345-ab123-cd456
text2, 54321-ab123-cd456
```

So far I've managed to get info from {}, using re module:

```
re.compile(r'.*{(.*)}
```

What I want to do is to get the rightmost text after "-" that is inside the double quotes, add comma and get info that is inside curly brackets. Can I do all of this in one step? In one regular expression? Or what could be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re    
lst = ['"Some-text" {12345-ab123-cd456}', '"Some-Another-text2" {54321-ab123-cd456}]']

regexp = re.compile(r'"\s*.+-(\S+)\s*"\s+{\s*(\S+)\s*}')
for i in lst:
    line = re.match(regexp, i)
    if line:
        print line.group(1) + ", " + line.group(2)
```

output:

```
text, 12345-ab123-cd456                                                                                       
text2, 54321-ab123-cd456
```

Comment: i didnt notice he wanted to cut out that part from the text, so here's the fixed regex

Comment: I would add `\s*` near `{ }` because your regexp will fail if the pattern inside brackets starts with space

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm using subprocess module to read process output into a list and later using regular expression on this list as you showed me. However, at the moment when I print out my list,it is inside of an extra brackets (like this: [['"Text" {12354-45123}', '"Text2" {12345-2435}' ]]). I think I can easily delete these brackets?

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expressions is a fine way to solve this if you're given this data initially as strings like you posted.

Expanding on what you already have,

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\-([^\-]*)"\s+{(.*)}')
>>> m = pattern.search('"Some-Another-text2" {54321-ab123-cd456}]')
>>> m.groups()
('text2', '54321-ab123-cd456')
```

Using this you can just loop through your data and `pattern.search` each string.

Comment: Another option: m = re.match('".*-(.*)"\s*{(.*)}', '"Some-Another-text" {54321-ab123-cd456}')

Answer (score 0):

Or, with simpler patterns:

```
import re
outlist = []
pat = re.compile('".*-(\w+)" {(.*)}', re.I)
for s in ['"Some-text" {12345-ab123-cd456}', '"Some-Another-text2" {54321-ab123-cd456}']:     
    m = re.match(pat, s)
    out = m.group(1) + ", "+ m.group(2)
    print(s)
    print(out)
    outlist.append(out)

print(outlist)
```

Which produces:

```
"Some-text" {12345-ab123-cd456}
text, 12345-ab123-cd456
"Some-Another-text2" {54321-ab123-cd456}
text2, 54321-ab123-cd456
['text, 12345-ab123-cd456', 'text2, 54321-ab123-cd456']
```

Comment: Same as @Kasra, I'd like to know what is wrong with this solution.

Comment: Ok, wrote a full answer! Thx

Comment: you need to just keep `text` and `text2`

Comment: Oh missed that! Thanks again!

Comment: why do you re-compile your regex pattern in the loop? thats the point of re.compile function... you can compile it and just use

Comment: You're right: edited. The loop was not present in the first answer I wrote. I forgot to put it out of the loop.